# How to save (not deploy) mkdocs to browse in HTML locally?

Tags: html, documentation, mkdocs

Is it possible to create documentation of certain projects within the `mkdocs` framework?

I am aware of server deployment via `mkdocs serve`. We can also once the documentation reached a certain level we like perform `mkdocs build` and this will create a `site` folder, which we can in fact download locally and browse by opening the index.html file.

This approach however is not perfect, as every time we can switch a tab, it runs into a between step where we have to manually matches with another HTML page we are interested in.

Is it possible to save how save the entire `mkdocs` locally or as a pdf?
It must be for local usage but without a server approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/deploying-your-docs/#local-files), you can set this values in `mkdocs.yml` configuration file:

```yaml
site_url: ""
use_directory_urls: False
```

`site_url` must be set to an empty string if you want to use `file://` scheme.

`use_directory_urls` should be set to `false` for links between pages to work correctly.

You also need to disable the search plugin or use another plugin, which supports `file://` scheme.

Note: *not every theme can display properly in offline mode*.